# Get total number of Azure functions in a subscription

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-graph

I'm trying to find a query to list total number of Azure functions within a subscription using Azure Resource Graph Explorer.

I'm only able to get the total number of Function Apps and not the underlying functions.

Is there a way using Graph query? Or is there a script which I can use?

Note: Only interested in Azure Functions not the Azure Function App.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible through a Resource Graph Query. One possible approach would be to use Azure REST API subsequently to get the results. Here is a PowerShell example:

You need to generate a Bearer token in order to query the REST API. You could use a function like this to generate it.

```
function Get-AzOauth2Token
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [string]$TenantId,
        [string]$AppId,
        [string]$Secret
    )

    $result         =   Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $('https://login.microsoftonline.com/'+$TenantId+'/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0') -Method Post -Body @{"grant_type" = "client_credentials"; "resource" = "https://management.core.windows.net/"; "client_id" = "$AppId"; "client_secret" = "$Secret" }
    $authorization  =   ("{0} {1}" -f $result.token_type, $result.access_token)
    return $authorization
}
```

There are a lot of other ways to get a token though. However, I will use this to retrieve it...

```
$token = Get-AzOauth2Token -TenantId your_tenant -AppId your_spn_app_id -Secret your_secret
```

Then you would run your resource graph query in order to get all Function Apps across the tenant and in any subscription.

```
$query = Search-AzGraph "resources | where type =~ 'microsoft.web/sites' | where kind startswith 'functionapp'"
$results = Search-AzGraph -Query $query
```

...and finally execute the REST API Calls for all the Function Apps that the query returned.

```
$functions = @()

$results | ForEach-Object {

    $restMethod = 'GET'
    $restUri    = 'https://management.azure.com'+$_.ResourceId+'/functions?api-version=2022-03-01'
    $restHeader = @{
        'Authorization' = $token
        'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
    }

    # Execute Call
    $request    = Invoke-RestMethod -Method $restMethod `
                                    -Uri $restUri `
                                    -Headers $restHeader

    $functions += $request

}
```

The `$functions.value` variable now holds all the different functions.

I suggest using the REST API instead of standard PowerShell cmdlets because it is faster in large environments - it prevents you from having to switch between subscriptions when you have resources spread across various subscriptions.

Comment: thanks for this. 
I think the above resource graph query is not listing all the function apps I've got in the subscription. 
Shouldn't it be?
resources | where type =~ 'microsoft.web/serverfarms' | where kind =~ 'functionapp'

Comment: Oh, spotted the mistake. The resource graph query didn't inlcude Function Apps that are running on Linux Plans. Edited the post. This should work better: `resources | where type =~ 'microsoft.web/sites' | where kind startswith 'functionapp'`

Querying for `microsoft.web/serverfarms` would only return the App Service Plans and only if they are Consumption Plans.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to achieve your requirement using the PowerShell script. Below is the script that worked for me.

```
$GetFunction=Get-AzFunctionApp -SubscriptionId <YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>
$ResourceGroup=($GetFunction).ResourceGroupName
$Name = ($GetFunction).Name
$Result=@()
For($I=0;$I -lt $ResourceGroup.count;$I++) {
        $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
                ResourceGroup = $ResourceGroup[$I]
                FunctionAppName = $Name[$I]
                Function=(Get-AzResource -ApiVersion "2022-03-01" -Name $Name[$I] -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup[$I] -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions").ResourceName
            }
            $Result+=$obj
}
$Result
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]

#### Update

To get the count of number of functions in a function app, you can use `.count`.

```
$GetFunction=Get-AzFunctionApp -SubscriptionId <YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>
$ResourceGroup=($GetFunction).ResourceGroupName
$Name = ($GetFunction).Name
$Result=@()
For($I=0;$I -lt $ResourceGroup.count;$I++) {
    $Functions=(Get-AzResource -ApiVersion "2022-03-01" -Name $Name[$I] -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup[$I] -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions").ResourceName
        $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
                ResourceGroup = $ResourceGroup[$I]
                FunctionAppName = $Name[$I]
                NoOfFunctions=$Functions.Count
                Functions=$Functions
    }
    $Result+=$obj
}
$Result
```

[image]

### Update-2

```
$GetFunction=Get-AzFunctionApp -SubscriptionId <YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>
$ResourceGroup=($GetFunction).ResourceGroupName
$Name = ($GetFunction).Name
$Result=@()
$TotalFuncCount=0
For($I=0;$I -lt $ResourceGroup.count;$I++) {
    $Functions=(Get-AzResource -ApiVersion "2022-03-01" -Name $Name[$I] -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup[$I] -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions").ResourceName
        $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
                ResourceGroup = $ResourceGroup[$I]
                FunctionAppName = $Name[$I]
                NoOfFunctions=$Functions.Count
                Functions=$Functions
    }
    $Result+=$obj
    $TotalFuncCount+=$Functions.Count
}
$Result
$TotalFuncCount
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Had to make some changes - to get this working
1. had to convert string to array (when 1 single resource group is present)
2. Set the subscription context inside the for loop else PS doesnt find the resourcegroup.

Comment: @user20056090 You can initialize a variable and add the NoOfFunctions for each iteration. Please check the updated answer.